# Iter through object and append if in group

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how to iter through a object, called 'item'.
'item' is from begining a response from a soap call. So an XML that I extracted into below. Then used 'xml.etree.ElementTre' to make it into 'item' with this.

```
xmlList = re.search('<getListResponse>(.+?)</getListResponse>', str(xmlList)).group(1)
item = ET.fromstring(xmlList)
```

Below is how it looked like before using ElementTree on the response.

```
<OL>
    <LI>
        <name>Foo</name>                        
        <type>Spam</type>
        <group>Wood</group>
        <....>ETC</....>
    </LI>
    <LI>
        <name>BAR</name>                        
        <type>Spam</type>
        <group>Iron</group>
        <....>ETC</....>
    </LI>
</OL>
```

And I want to create a new list where I can choose every 'NAME' from each 'LI' where the 'GROUP' is 'WOOD'.

I'm new to this and all I figured out is this.

```
 for a in item.iter('name'):            
    woodList.append(a.text)
```

This takes all 'NAME' from all 'GROUP'. I tried with some IF. But can't find right syntax to check which 'GROUP' it belongs to.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what `item` is. How is it structured? What kind of object is it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is a great lib for handling this sort of query

(pip install bs4)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_str =    "<OL><LI><name>Foo</name><type>Spam</type><group>Wood</group><....>ETC</....></LI><LI><name>BAR</name><type>Spam</type><group>Iron</group><....>ETC</....></LI></OL>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str,'html.parser')

li_list = soup.find_all('li')

for li in li_list:    
    if li.find('group').get_text() == "Wood":
        print li.find('name').get_text() + ' has wood'    
    else:
        print li.find('name').get_text() + ' has not'
```